# adding List of objects to Context in ef

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Is it possible to add list of object to Context in entity framework without using foreach addObject ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Generally you can't do that - you have to do it in a loop. In some cases, however, you can avoid adding every object - specifically, if you have an entity graph and you add the parent node. E.g. if you have a `Company` object that has a collection of `Employees`:

```
context.AddToCompanies(company);

/* The following loop is not necessary */
/* The employees will be saved together with the company */
/*
foreach (var employee in company.Employees)
{
    context.AddToEmployees(employee);
}*/

context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 63):

From EntityFramework 6 you can use [DbSet.AddRange Method (IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.entity.dbset.addrange(v=vs.113).aspx) like this

```
db.companies.AddRange(newCompanies);
```

Answer (score 11):

Using linq and some lambdas you can seed it easily like this.

**Note: Regarding your current version you can do**

```
List<Company> companies = new List<Company>();

companies.ForEach(n => context.AddToCompanies(n));
```

This is the way I do with *Entity Framework 4.1 or higher with the Code First Approach*

```
List<RelationshipStatus> statuses = new List<RelationshipStatus>()
{
    new RelationshipStatus(){Name = "Single"},
    new RelationshipStatus(){Name = "Exclusive Relationship"},
    new RelationshipStatus(){Name = "Engaged"},
    new RelationshipStatus(){Name = "Married"},
    new RelationshipStatus(){Name = "Open Relationship"},
    new RelationshipStatus(){Name = "Commited Relationship"}
};

statuses.ForEach(n => myContext.RelationshipStatuses.Add(n));
myContext.SaveChanges();
```

The Context was Setup as follows

```
public class MyContext:DbContext
{
     public DbSet<RelationshipStatus> RelationshipStatuses{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via navigation property. I came across the same problem and I did not feel good using loops.

If you have a Student table and a Subject Table. You will have one to many relationship between Table Student and Table Subject respectively. A navigation property in Student table will be `public IEnumerable<Subject> Subjects {get; set;}` and a navigation property in Subject table will be `public Student Student {get;set;}`.

If you want to use loop, you will use the navigation property `Student`, and if you want to add all the instances of Subjects in Subjects table with corresponding Student, you will use the navigation property `Subjects`.

**How to Use?**
Suppose you have objects ready to map, I mean you have added the fields in Student and in Subjects.

**Now**
`student.Subjects = subjects'
then add student using your`DbContext`
**OR**
As explained in @Yakimych answer above (commented though).

I have not implemented this in EF but in EF Core 3.1. However, most of the future readers will benefit from this answer including the ones using EF and not EF Core.

Answer (score -6):

Yes you can, like

```
List<Employee> empList = this.context.Employee.ToList();
```