# Save list of entity with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

How can I save a list of enitty into the database using Entity Framework Code First?

I have problem saving the list of entity.

Below is the code I have written:

```
List<Account> accounts = ActivateAccount();

// Save merchant account & bank information into database
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    try
    {
        context.Accounts.Attach(accounts);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are these new accounts or existing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the below link. Difference between Attach and AddToObject

[Entity Framework 4 - AddObject vs Attach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920111/entity-framework-4-addobject-vs-attach)

Please clarify are you updating disconnected records or adding records. Below is the code to add records in DB.

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    try
    {
        foreach(var row in accounts){
            context.AddToAccounts(row);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        //Log any exception here.
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Account> accounts = ActivateAccount();

// Save merchant account & bank information into database
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    try
    {
        context.Accounts.Add(accounts);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Try replacing Attach method with Add

Answer (score 0):

I found several ways to do it in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/12853252/7287324

Hope it solves your problem.